# Translating validation error messages in a custom FormType

Tags: forms, symfony, localization, symfony-forms, symfony-validator

I have the current situation

```
<?php

namespace MyBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class MyFormType extends AbstractType implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    use \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $translator = $this->container->get('translator');

        $builder->add('my-field', 'text', [
            'constraints' => [
                new Assert\NotBlank([
                    'message' => $translator->trans('%field% should not be blank.', ['%field%' => $translator->trans('MyFieldName')]),
                ]),
            ],
        ]);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_form';
    }
}
```

This example already works, I am trying to refactor it so I don't have to include the container (or the translator) in it.

The challenge lies in keeping

- '%field% should not be blank.' and
- 'MyFieldName'

as the only two translatable strings, 'cause it's likely that MyFieldName is going to be translated already (like for labels) leaving '%field% should not be blank.' as a generic message valid for any field in the site.

Comment: Removed "placeholders" from the title, as people seem to be confused by it.

Answer (score 0):

Past into constraints
'attr' => array(
             'placeholder' => 'Message',
        )

Comment: When I say placeholders I mean http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#message-placeholders not html placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

If you have activated the translator in **symfony framework** config by uncommenting this line :

`#translator: { fallbacks: [%locale%] }`

in `config.yml`, all error messages of violations set by the validator are translated by default with values from `validators` domain.

You should us either `app/Resources/translations/validators.(_format)` or
`src/(Acme/)*Bundle/Resources/translations/validators.(_format)` to define your custom messages and once done clear your cache.

example :

```
# app/Resources/translations/validators.yml
my_form:
    errors:
       my_field:
           not_blank: My field should not be blank
```

and

```
// FormType
$builder->add('my-field', 'text', [
        'constraints' => [
            new Assert\NotBlank([
                'message' => 'my_form.errors.my_field.not_blank',
            ]),
        ],
    ]);
```

Error messages from validator will be automatically translated.

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translating-constraint-messages

Comment: Yes they will, but that's not what I am asking. What I am asking if it's possible to do what I *am* doing in the example above without using the translator IN the form class.